# Enable universal link only for specific page / path

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

I've read through how to configure the paths to enable universal link, and I want to have it enabled only for specific page, e.g.

I would like it to be enabled with the following page ONLY:

```
https://example.com/path/enabled.html
```

while other pages like:

```
https://example.com/path/notEnabled.html
```

should not have it enabled, i.e. I should not have that "Open with myAppAnme" banner on the top if I swipe downward at the latter page.

And in order to achieve this, I have the `apple-app-site-association` file at server set up as below:

```
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "teamPrefix.com.app.bundleID",
            "paths": [ "/path/enabled.html", "NOT /path/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I browse `https://example.com/path/notEnabled.html` with Safari and swipe down, the banner for universal link appear as in the enabled page, which I do not want it to. Is there any way to only enable it for specific page or I set the config the wrong way?

Thanks!

**Note:** I've also tried `"NOT *"` and `"NOT /"` but the banner still appear in pages which are not supposed to have it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the banner is controlled by a meta tag in your HTML, not in the `apple-app-site-association` file. Check the source of you HTML and verify you don't have the required meta tag for the banner